# Why would someone who is charged with murder appear before Westminster (or any other) Magistrates Court?

Tags: england-and-wales, criminal-procedure, murder

According to media reports, NX121 is set to appear at Westminster Magistrates Court. But isn’t murder an indictable only offence?

Comment: When you refer to media reports, please consider linking to at least one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

There is always a first hearing in magistrates' court.

The magistrates' court hears the defendant's plea, decides where to send the case for trial or sentencing and decides bail.

Some offences, 'indictable only' offences such as murder, are always tried and sentenced in Crown Court. But the first hearing - not the trial - is in magistrates' court.

https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/going-to-court/information-for-defendants/

https://www.cps.gov.uk/sites/default/files/documents/victims_witnesses/A-guide-for-victims-what-happens-when-a-case-comes-to-the-CPS-0823.pdf